# Heroku error: Cannot find module 'optimizer' causing internal server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my `node.js` app on `Heroku` and when i open it, it gives me an `internal server error`. When i check the logs, t says `Cannot find module optmizer`. I don't use anything called optmizer in the project. When running it on localhost, it works perfectly but no idea as to why it asking about a missing module. I've also tried installing the `optmizer module` but doesn't seem to do anything

app.js

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
const flash = require('connect-flash');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();
app.use(flash());

app.use(session({
  cookie: { maxAge: 6000 },
  secret: 'futuresonic',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'MyWebApp', message: req.flash('success'), sessionFlash: res.locals.sessionFlash});
});

app.get('/done', (req, res) => {
  res.render('done');
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.success = req.flash('success');
  res.locals.info = req.flash('info');
  res.locals.errors = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css'));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  next(createError(404))
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyWebApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "firebase": "^5.8.6",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.0.0",
    "flash": "^1.1.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "pug": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/node": "^11.11.3"
  }
}
```

Heroku logs

```
2019-03-15T11:35:26.247394+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
2019-03-15T11:35:26.247433+00:00 app[web.1]: designed for a production environment, as it will leak
2019-03-15T11:35:26.247436+00:00 app[web.1]: memory, and will not scale past a single process.
2019-03-15T11:35:26.981657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-03-15T11:35:28.691683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=pure-hamlet-86611.herokuapp.com request_id=1bcb11de-4b03-44fd-9835-7b48f0e2bf4b fwd="109.69.85.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=129ms status=500 bytes=569 protocol=https
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690100+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './optimizer/level-0/optimize'
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690112+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690115+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690117+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690118+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690120+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/clean-css/lib/clean.js:8:22)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690122+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690124+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690125+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690127+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-03-15T11:35:28.690129+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
```

Comment: Do you see `optimizer` in your `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`? Is whichever of these files you're using checked in to version control?

Comment: No i didnt check them in. The problem seems to be coming from `heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=pure-hamlet-86611.herokuapp.com request_id=1bcb11de-4b03-44fd-9835-7b48f0e2bf4b fwd="109.69.85.106" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=129ms status=500 bytes=569 protocol=https`

Comment: Whichever lock file you're using should be tracked and pushed to Heroku. That's the file that ensures your production environment has all the right libraries installed at the right version. Unlike `package.json`, it includes indirect dependencies, exact version numbers, and checksums.

Comment: yah thats checked into version control

Comment: @sk123 Have you fix this problem `2019-03-15T11:35:28.690100+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module './optimizer/level-0/optimize'`?

Comment: I did manage to fix it

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message after updating my version of pug to 2.0.3 and running `npm audit`. Not sure why. To fix I changed my package.json pug version to 2.0.0, deleted my package-lock.json, and recreated it using `npm install`.